# Any java package to draw simple geometric shape?

Tags: java, image, draw

Does anyone have any suggestion about any lib/package to draw simple geometric, such as triangle, square?  It can be saved into a png format.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here, and say that what I think you are asking can be achieved using `BufferedImage` `Graphics` and `ImageIO` but I'm not certain

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is. I googled a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to have a look at the Java 2D API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/index.html

Answer (score 8):

This source uses `Graphics2D` of the Java 2D API to draw some simple colored shapes.

For reference, here are the 32x32 images that result.

[image][image][image][image]
[image][image][image][image]
[image][image][image][image]
[image][image][image][image]
[image][image][image][image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleImages {

    public static BufferedImage getColoredShapeImage(
            int size, Shape shape, Color color) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fill(shape);
        g.dispose();

        return bi;
    }

    public static Shape getPointedShape(int points, int radius) {
        double angle = Math.PI * 2 / points;

        GeneralPath p = new GeneralPath();
        for (int ii = 0; ii < points; ii++) {
            double a = angle * ii;

            double x = (Math.cos(a) * radius) + radius;
            double y = (Math.sin(a) * radius) + radius;
            if (ii == 0) {
                p.moveTo(x, y);
            } else {
                p.lineTo(x, y);
            }
        }
        p.closePath();

        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Color[] colors = {
            Color.RED,
            Color.GREEN,
            Color.BLUE,
            Color.YELLOW
        };
        File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        f = new File(f, "ShapedImages");
        f.mkdirs();
        for (Color c : colors) {
            for (int s = 15; s < 31; s += 15) {
                Shape sh = new Ellipse2D.Double(1, 1, 2 * s, 2 * s);
                BufferedImage i = getColoredShapeImage((2 * s) + 2, sh, c);
                String name = "Image"
                        + "0point-"
                        + s + "px-"
                        + c.getRed() + "r-"
                        + c.getGreen() + "g-"
                        + c.getBlue() + "b"
                        + ".png";
                File t = new File(f, name);
                ImageIO.write(i, "png", t);
                for (int ii = 3; ii < 7; ii++) {
                    sh = getPointedShape(ii, s);
                    i = getColoredShapeImage((2 * s) + 2, sh, c);
                    name = "Image"
                            + ii + "point-"
                            + s + "px-"
                            + c.getRed() + "r-"
                            + c.getGreen() + "g-"
                            + c.getBlue() + "b"
                            + ".png";
                    t = new File(f, name);
                    ImageIO.write(i, "png", t);
                }
            }
        }
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
    }
}
```

### Interface `GeometricShapeImages`

```
/**
 * Interface for accessing the images seen in
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/16052085/418556
 */
interface GeometricShapeImages {

    public static final int BLUE = 0;
    public static final int GREEN = 1;
    public static final int RED = 2;
    public static final int YELLOW = 3;

    public static final int CIRCLE = 0;
    public static final int TRIANGLE = 1;
    public static final int DIAMOND = 2;
    public static final int PENTAGON = 3;
    public static final int HEXAGON = 4;

    /**
     * Stores a String representation of the URL for the colored shape image.
     * Can be accessed like GeometricShapeImages.URL[DIAMOND][BLUE]
     */
    public static final String[][] URL = {
        { // CIRCLE
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmeJ.png", // BLUE
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5uTa.png", // GREEN
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCF8S.png", // RED
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHARa.png" // YELLOW
        }, // END: CIRCLE
        { // TRIANGLE
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5DGx.png", // BLUE
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYxHm.png", // GREEN
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v2TX.png", // RED
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BGfi.png" // YELLOW
        }, // END: TRIANGLE
        { // DIAMOND
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/in9g1.png", // BLUE
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lgtq.png", // GREEN
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0JHK.png", // RED
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZXhi.png" // YELLOW
        }, // END: DIAMOND
        { // PENTAGON
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IucNt.png", // BLUE
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBOv3.png", // GREEN
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EVv1.png", // RED
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqkl0.png" // YELLOW
        }, // END: PENTAGON
        { // HEXAGON
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoKxT.png", // BLUE
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ8am.png", // GREEN
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj49g.png", // RED
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/c67nr.png" // YELLOW
        } // END: HEXAGON
    };
}
```