# Java Intersection Error

Tags: java, awt, intersection, java-2d

I have this code for my DoLogic method. And I'm trying to do a intersection between the shots and the obstacles but I really can't think of nothing.. cause both are different objects.. i tried to do some but it didn't really detect something at all.

```
for(int i=0; i<shots.length; i++)
{
    if(shots[i] != null)
    {
        shots[i].moveShot(SHOTSPEED);
        if(shots[i].getXPos() > 1280)
        {
            shots[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
for(int i=0; i<obstacles.length; i++)
{
    if(obstacles[i] == null) 
    { 
        obstacles[i] = generateObstacle(); 
        break;
    } 
    if(obstacles[i] != null)
    {
        obstacles[i].moveObstacle(); 
        if(obstacles[i].getXPos() < 10) 
        { 
            obstacles[i] = null; 
        }
        else if(obstacles[i].intersects(Player1.character))
        {
            obstacles[i] = null;
            GameSounds.hit("/resources/8bit_bomb_explosion.wav");
            lives--;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you guys give me an example or at least an advice how to do an intersection between an obstacle and a shot?

Comment: Do these classes implement [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html)?  If not, they should.  See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556) for an SSCCE.

Comment: and i should implement the Rectangle in Obstacle and Oval in shot? cause that's what they are drawn as

Comment: and how do i implement? i just type implements Shape?

Comment: please whats isn't clear, and don't to load whatever on runtime, meaning GameSounds.hit("/resources/8bit_bomb_explosion.wav");, load this Object to local variable, on apps startup

Comment: i will do that later but i can't do the intersection

Comment: how do i make 2 objects from 2 different arraylists intersect?

Comment: as shown above the obstacles are sometimes null..

Answer (score 1):

Do these classes implement [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html)? If not, they should.  See the answer to [Collision detection with complex shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14574045/418556) for an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

[image]

> ..and i should implement the Rectangle in Obstacle and Oval in shot?

That seems logical to me, from your description of both objects.

> ..i just type implements Shape?

I would tend to use a [`Rectangle2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html) or [`Rectangle2D.Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Double.html) for the obstacle & an [`Ellipse2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) or [`Ellipse2D.Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.Double.html) for the shot.  Rather than extend them, just hold them as an instance variable.

Give it a go & let us know how you go.  If you get stuck, post an SSCCE of your best attempt.
You might need to hot-link to [some small images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16052085/418556).

[image] .. [image] ..

Comment: same for ellipse2D .. it tells me to create an interface and if i try to implement rectangle to obstacle it tells me that it can't be a superinterface of obstacle.. cause an superinterface should be an interface